# Firewall setting for C2DM

Tags: ip, firewall, android-c2dm, fqdn

I just developed one testing app in Android system, and try to use WiFi connection for C2DM push, but IT dept. hope that I can provide C2DM IP address for opening Firewall port:5228. 
Does anyone know the IP address or FQDN for Google C2DM server ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hostname/FQDN for C2DM service = android.apis.google.com

The push service uses a load balancing scheme that yields a different IP address for the same hostname.

The following link provides IP ranges of google cloud.
http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/google-ip-address.htm

So you can specify that ranges in your firewall rules.

Ports needed to support Enterprise Mobility Management (Both IOS and Android)
https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB70276&actp=LIST